# How do I generate a 404 error from an HttpModule?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have an ASP.NET HttpModule that handles HttpApplication.BeginRequest to redirect some requests to other files.  Typically I'll do something like parse the request, write a file to HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream then call HttpApplication.CompleteRequest().  For some requests I can't find the relevant file - how do I return a 404 error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");`?